# How can I apply online for a UK Residence Card?

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit, residence-cards

I'm an extended family member of an EEA National (British citizen living in the UK) and I'm from Pakistan. I want to apply for a Residence Card as an extended family member of an EEA National living in the UK, but I can't find an online link to do it.

The official website [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card/apply) takes you to the online application for a PERMANENT Residence Card, instead of a Residence Card, which comes after the Permanent Residence Card.

I've found forms for my kind of application, but I'm unable to find a way to apply online while even the links in the forms [PDF] say there's a way to apply online.

Please can you tell me where can I apply online? As filling in forms on paper is difficult and time taking and also prone to errors if nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can only apply online in connection with your EEA family member's application for a permanent residence document](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card/apply):

> ## 4. Apply
>
> The qualified person can include you if they [apply online for permanent residence](https://www.gov.uk/eea-registration-certificate/permanent-residence).
>
> Otherwise, you must download and fill in either the:
>
> - [application for a direct family member](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/apply-for-a-registration-certificate-or-residence-card-for-a-family-member-form-eea-fm), form EEA (FM)
> - [application for an extended family member](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/apply-for-a-registration-certificate-or-residence-card-for-an-extended-family-member-form-eea-efm), form EEA (EFM)
>
> > Find out [which application form you should use](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card/eligibility).
>
> Post it to the Home Office, using the address on the form. Include the fee and supporting documents listed on the form.
>
> ## Fees
>
> It costs £65 for each person to apply.

Comment: So you are saying the online application is ONLY for permanent residence?
And NOT for "simpler or first" residence card and an applicant can ONLY apply via form via post?

Comment: Also this "The qualified person can include you if they apply online for permanent residence." doesn't apply to me because my sponsor/family is already a citizen of UK for over 30-35 years.

Comment: @SaifAli (1) Does your family member qualify under the [Surinder Singh route](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/surinder-singh)?  Otherwise, you cannot immigrate under the EEA regulations.  (2) if your family member *does* qualify under Surinder Singh then you must apply by post because, as you note, the online permanent residence application is inapplicable.

Comment: no the family member neither my/our case qualify under the Suriner Singh route. I'm applying as an extended-family member of an EEA National (UK citizen) residing in the UK and is exercising his Free Movement Treaty rights. 

"you cannot immigrate under the EEA regulations"? Am I missing something? I wanted to apply via EEA Family Permit but since I'll have a 2 year general visitor visa and the EEA Family Permit is just used to enter the UK and then you've to apply for a Residence Card again if you are an extended family member to stay for more than 6 months.

Comment: But as I can already enter the UK legally and the law allows me to change my visa/immigration status I believe I can do this. Right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/family-permit 

This is the description page of the family permit. And it's not a requirement to have a EEA Family Permit beforehand to apply for an extended family of EEA National Residence Card I've learnt on Gov.UK site.

Comment: @SaifAli "am I missing something?" Yes: The term *EEA national* does not include British citizens unless the Surinder Singh route is applicable.  In other words, you cannot use the EEA regulations if your sponsor is a British citizen unless the sponsor qualifies under Surinder SIngh.  The fact that Surinder Singh is described on the EEA family permit page is not significant.  Notice how it is also mentioned at https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card/eligibility.  Instead of the EEA Regulations, only the Immigration Rules apply, and I don't think the Rules recognize "extended" family.

Comment: @SaifAli the routes under the Immigration Rules are described at https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa.  Of course, you can always mail in your application for a residence card, but it will be refused.

Comment: @SaifAli you said "I'm applying as an extended-family member of an EEA National (UK citizen) residing in the UK and is exercising his Free Movement Treaty rights": European courts have consistently ruled that an EU citizen living in his own country of nationality is not "exercising treaty rights" because the right to live in one's country of citizenship does not depend on the treaty.  That's why your British citizen relative isn't an "EEA national" for this purpose.

Comment: I think there's some sort of miscommunication. An EEA National can of course be from any of the 26 (or more) countries and be a citizen of them, the national's direct family enjoys automatic rights to free movement upon application and extended-family on case-basis.
While the Surinder Singh is a completely separate route, it's not the only route to join a EEA National family/relative, I've read the bills and rules and they allow me to apply, there was even a similar case like mine (in relation) used as a example in one of the official texts/documents.

Comment: I suggest you to please go through the _eligibility_ and other relevant text. Also you'll find/realize that **Surinder Singh** is _ONE_ of the routes and _NOT_ the _ONLY_ routes.

Comment: But I think I've got the answer that Residence Card application has to be mailed in by hand to the Home Office. But still I contacted the Gov.UK support staff, their official response will be soon here! :)

Comment: @SaifAli Surinder Singh is the only route that applies to family of British citizens, however.  From the [regulations](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2016/1052): "“EEA national” means a national of an EEA State who is not also a British citizen."  From the [directive](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616): "This Directive shall apply to all Union citizens who move to or reside in a Member State *other than that of which they are a national,"* (emphasis added).  Otherwise there never would have been a Surinder Singh case in the first place.

Comment: amazing! very sharp! How could have I missed this?
So I can't join my relative via this route? Any idea, with the above (my) case, how can I join my relative in the UK?

I'm going to mark the question answered though.

Comment: @SaifAli I think we've long since reached the point where you ought to ask a new question, but I fear that the answer will be that there is no family-based route available to you (depending on the exact relationship between you and your family member).